# Sencha cmd4 does not copy Touch SDK library

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha, I have been trying to generate Sencha-2.3.1a (latest SDK) app structure using Sencha CMD 4 using this command:

```
sencha generate app exampleApp .\exampleApp
```

According to the doc (http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/command_app_touch), it should create a library called Touch.

```
touch/                  # A copy of the Sencha Touch SDK
    cmd/                # Sencha Touch-specific content for Sencha Cmd
        sencha.cfg      # Configuration file for Sencha Cmd
        plugin.xml      # Plugin for Sencha Cmd
    src/                # The Sench Touch source
    sencha-touch-*.js   # Pre-compiled and bootstrap files
    ...
```

But the library was not created, this is the generated structure:

[image]

and index.html does not reference any sencha-touch-*.js, it only references the following:

```
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

**Can somebody explain what was changed?**

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your app in sencha touch library folder - it should be outside. For example:

```
cd /htdocs # or where is your web server document root
sencha -sdk /sencha/touch-2.3.1 generate app exampleApp example-app
cd example-app
ls -l .
```

For more info see [this video](http://extjs.eu/videos/#create-workspace)